# Demystifying Nikola Tesla: Scientifically sound, historically accurate biography

Tags: biographical-details, electromagnetism, physicists, book-recommendation, tesla

As any physicist knows, a lot of amateur science afficionados out there bring up Nikola Tesla in rather fantastical ways. There are indeed a few reasons for his near mythical status in popular culture, but us physicists don't learn a lot about him during our training.

What scientifically sound and historically accurate biography of Nikola Tesla would you recommend, so that I know what to say the next time some guy assures me that Tesla came up with a free energy source but the industry shut it down and hid it from us? Or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good bet is Christopher Cooper's *The Truth about Tesla: The Myth of the Lone Genius in the History of Innovation*, published in 2015 by Race Point Publishers.